# Android SQLite Cursor slow when calling function

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I tested my app in `MotoG 2nd Gen (1GB RAM, Quad-core 1.2 GHz)`. I have the following static method in a class `Misc`. The `itemRates` array is an `Object` array of length : 132 containing Strings of around length of 50 characters:-

```
public static double getDCRate(String item){
    for(int i=0;i<itemRates.length;i++){
        String ar[] = (itemRates[i]+"").split("[;]");
        if(ar[0].equals(item)){
            return Double.parseDouble(ar[1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, in my `AsyncTask`, I call this function as shown below:-

```
/* db initialized */
                Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
/* ... */
                double totalCost = 0.0;
                double ntwt_double = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Ntwt"));

                totalCost += Misc.getDCRate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DN1")))*(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("DP1"))/100)*ntwt_double;
                totalCost += Misc.getDCRate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DN2")))*(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("DP2"))/100)*ntwt_double;
                totalCost += Misc.getDCRate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DN3")))*(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("DP3"))/100)*ntwt_double;
                totalCost += Misc.getDCRate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DN4")))*(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("DP4"))/100)*ntwt_double;
                totalCost += Misc.getDCRate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DN5")))*(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("DP5"))/100)*ntwt_double;
                totalCost += Misc.getDCRate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DN6")))*(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("DP6"))/100)*ntwt_double;
                totalCost += Misc.getDCRate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DN7")))*(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("DP7"))/100)*ntwt_double;
                totalCost += Misc.getDCRate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DN8")))*(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("DP8"))/100)*ntwt_double;
```

It takes around 12 seconds for the `AsyncTask` to complete..Eh?! Fairly large for itering a small array. To check that it was the function call, I removed the function calls to find the `AsyncTask` completing in about 1 second! Point to be noted is that I use the same lines of code in my swing application, which is also a Java framework. So why does it take so much time to execute in android? Any idea how to solve this dilemma?

Comment: Have you tried profiling? It will give you a better idea of where the time is being spent.

Comment: @matiash, thanks for your tip. Look at my answer. Can you think of any reason why `split` consumes so much time and memory in android but in swing it is just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @matiash I profiled the method and found that `split(..)` was the main culprit. Don't know why but the methods `split`,`Patter.splitter`..and other methods amounted to 52% of the total computation time. Weird though, after using a replacement for `split`, the `AsyncTask` loads in about 2 seconds.

Comment: Hadn't seen this with `split()` so far, but once I had a similar problem with `format()`. Happy you managed to solve it.